# IndexError: image index out of range?

Tags: python, numpy, winapi, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make an screen color detector so basically you tell it the values of the color of what you  want to find. But the error i run into is `IndexError: image index out of range`

My Code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import numpy as np


def Color(R,G,B):

    px = ImageGrab.grab().load()
    
    x = GetSystemMetrics(0)
    y = GetSystemMetrics(1)  

    color = px[x, y]

    if color is R and G and B:
        print("Found The color you want!")
                
        
Color(25, 35, 45) #Telling it the RGB value of what i want to find
```

is there better way to do this?

Comment: I edited my answer to be more useful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because `x` and `y` are essentially lengths in a zero-based system. At the very least you would want `color = px[x-1, y-1]` ... if you wanted to check the very last pixel on the screen.

Maybe you are trying to do something more like this?

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x :int
    y :int
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'x={self.x}, y={self.y}'


def ColorPositions(R,G,B):
    px   = ImageGrab.grab().load()
    x, y = GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1) 
    return [Point(n%x, n//x) for n in range(x*y) if px[n%x, n//x]==(R, G, B)]
        

positions = ColorPositions(99, 99, 99)
print(*positions[0:10], sep="\n")
```